# Unfortunately you app has stopped on startup droid

Tags: android, locale

I get this error on startup of the application.Here is my code

> ```
>    package com.mycompany.myapp.android;
>      import java.util.Locale;
>      import android.app.Application;
>      import android.content.SharedPreferences;
>      import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
>      import android.content.res.Configuration;
>      import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
>      import com.droidux.components.DroidUxLib;
>      import com.mycompany.myapp.R;
>       public class MyApp extends Application {
> /**
>  * Called when the application is starting, before any activity, service, or
>  * receiver objects (excluding content providers) have been created.
>  */
>   private Locale locale = null;
> @Override
> public void onCreate() {
>     super.onCreate();
>     // register the DroidUX library here
>     DroidUxLib.register("sakldsadkdla",
>             this);
>     SharedPreferences settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
>     String lang = settings.getString(getString(R.string.locale_lang), "");
>     changeLang(lang); 
> }
> public void changeLang(String lang) {
>     Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
>     if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
>         Editor ed = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit();
>         ed.putString(getString(R.string.locale_lang), lang);
>         ed.commit();
>         locale = new Locale(lang);
>         Locale.setDefault(locale);
>         Configuration conf = new Configuration(config);
>         conf.locale = locale;
>         getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
>     }
>    }    
>     }
> ```

I have no log, the client is reporting on startup of application on nexus 5... he is getting unfortunately myapp has stopped error.
What could this error be down too?

Comment: You do have a log -- it is in Logcat.

Comment: i dont have the device, client is reporting to me this error while he used nexus 5

Comment: on every device its working, bar this device.

Comment: Are any devices you tested running 4.4.2 (what nexus 5 is running)? i would recommend making a nexus 5 emulator and test on that to see if there is a crash.

Comment: nope, some other personed tested it on nexus 5 and it worked fine. I also tested it on my nexus 4 ( kitkat 4.4.2 ) and it works fine. it baffles me why its not working on with that particular user on nexus 5.